# Can you help me debug my session time out function?

Tags: php, security, debugging, session, timeout

Hi I am creating secure login functionality for my site. I have a function called sessionTimeOut() which i call at the top of each page of my site. As you can see within the function, if the user has been inactive for more than 30 mintues, I call a logOut() function and also a secure_session_start() function before redirecting the user back to the login page. I'm wondering will these functions execute fully before the redirect occurs? I'm not sure of the best way to debug the code. any help would be appreciated thanks.

```
function sessionTimeOut(){
    //We implement a session timeout of our own. We use a simple time stamp that denotes the time of the last activity (i.e. request) 
    //and update it with every request

    if(isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) {
        //last request was more than 30 minutes ago
        logOut(); 
        //start a new secure session so that we can create a new session variable.
        secure_session_start();

        //create a session variable to say that the login session has timed out after redirecting to the login page.
        $_SESSION['loginTimedOut'] = true;
        header('Location: login.php');
        exit();

    }
    $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); //update last activity time stamp

    //Now we also use an additional time stamp to regenerate the session ID periodically to avoid attacks on sessions
    if(!isset($_SESSION['CREATED'])) {
        $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();
    }else if(time() - $_SESSION['CREATED'] > 1800) {
        //session started more than 30 minutes ago
        session_regenerate_id(true);    //change session ID for the current session and invalidate old session ID
        $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();  //update creation time
    }
}
```

logout() function:

```
function logOut(){
    //Unset all session values 
    $_SESSION = array();

    //get session parameters 
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();

    // Delete the actual cookie. 
    setcookie(session_name(),
            '', time() - 42000, 
            $params["path"], 
            $params["domain"], 
            $params["secure"], 
            $params["httponly"]);

    // Destroy session 
    session_destroy();
}



function secure_session_start() {
    /* This is a function to start a PHP session in a secure way.
     * This function stops crackers accessing the session id cookie through JavaScript (for example in an XSS attack).
     * Also the session_regenerate_id() function, which regenerates the session id on every page reload, helps prevent session hijacking
     */
    $session_name = 'secure_session_id';   // Set a custom session name
    $secure = false; //set to true if https
        //This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
        $httponly = true;
        //Forces sessions to only use cookies.
        if(ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
            header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
            exit();
        }
        //Gets current cookies params.
        $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
        session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
        $cookieParams["path"], 
        $cookieParams["domain"], 
        $secure,
        $httponly);

    //Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();            //Start the PHP session 
        session_regenerate_id(true);    //regenerate the session, delete the old one to prevent session fixation attacks.
}
```

Comment: A method I commonly use is to comment out the Header redirects and use Echo to output information at different steps in the code to catch where it ends. Additionally, output buffering can help in some circumstances. http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Comment: PHP waits for the function to return before it performs the next action - so the answer to, *"will these functions execute fully before the redirect occurs?"* is "yes".

Comment: *Hm...*, pretty sure the session needs to be started before using `$_SESSION = array();`. I could be wrong though, but am next to certain. Same goes for the `sessionTimeOut()` function.

Comment: @fred-ii thanks.. I am starting the session on every page with this function secure_session_start(), before calling the timeout function so thats ok...

Comment: @Jay Blanchard that helps to know. thanks :)